Specific codomain of a metric
Given $(X,d)$ a metric space and $a \in [0,\infty)$. Is it possible to have to codomain of $d$ be the set $[0,a) \cup (a,\infty)$? In other words, can we find a metric on some space such that the distance between points is never $a$, while every other positive distance is achieved. I'm looking for either a working example or a proof that this is impossible.
Some facts that may be useful:
Since any metric is continuous and $[0,a) \cup (a,\infty)$ is disconnected, $X \times X$ must be disconnected. Hence $X$ must be disconnected.

A small suggestion, even though you specify what you mean, your question is really "Is there a metric space such that the range of $d$ is the set...". The distinction between co-domain and range is important, since the question about the co-domain is quite trivial.

A significantly more general result is true: Given any subset $A$ of non-negative real numbers, there is a metric space such that the metric has $A$ as it's range.

For simplicity, I'll let $a = 1$. Then consider the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$:
$$X_n = [2n,2n+1)$$
The set $$X = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}X_n \cup \{-3\} $$
Satisfies your requirements.
*Edit, the addition of $-3$ to the set was a correction pointed out by @Nitrodon in the comments

This excludes all odd integer distances, not just 1.  This can be fixed by adding either {-3} or {-1} to the set (depending on whether the convention you use has $0 \in \mathbb{N}$).
